# How do I get a multi colored border?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I have a circle that is filled based on percentage, but I need it to have a multi color border, i.e. 0-.10 is orange, .10-.50 is blue, .50-.70 is purple, and .70-1 is black.

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPointMake(cell.progress.frame.width / 2, cell.progress.frame.height / 2), radius: CGFloat(60), startAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI_2), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2 * percentage - M_PI_2), clockwise: true)

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath


    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0

    cell.progress.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Comment: Please provide a picture of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Something like this, different ranges should have different colors https://www.google.com/search?q=multi+color+circle+border&safe=strict&espv=2&biw=1164&bih=641&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrwO-Kk-TMAhWKPCYKHYVLBbAQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=CJTN91lRO2WmVM%3A

Comment: Cool! I thought that might be what you meant...

Comment: You're going to have to use multiple `CAShapeLayers` for that – [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090451/circular-uiview-with-multiple-coloured-border-working-like-a-pie-chart), although obj-c, may be useful.

Comment: @originaluser2 He _could_ use multiple shape layers, but he doesn't _have_ to; he could use no shape layer at all.

Comment: @matt True, "*have to*" was a bit strong (alas, past the 5 minute window now). Although layers are generally preferred if you ever want to consider animating them in the future.

Comment: @originaluser2 Good point.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way; you are certainly not going to do this with a single shape layer. But you can readily construct a drawing (in code) where you make successive arcs in different colors. For example:

[image]

That was achieved by a repeated sequence of calls to         CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor, CGContextAddArc, and CGContextStrokePath.

Comment: So I would have to create multiple arcs and add it to the circle I created above?